# Custom Null-Safety annotation is invalid in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Infomation about custom Null-Safety annotation is from Kotlin official:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

My java codes:

```
@TypeQualifierNickname
@javax.annotation.Nonnull(when = When.ALWAYS)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NN {
}

@NN
public static <T> T notNull(@Nullable T nullable, String message) throws NullPointerException {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(nullable, message);
}
```

Error calling:

```
fun max(comparator: Comparator<in T>): T {
    val maxOrNull: T? = ...


    // IDEA error:
    // Type mismatch.
    // Required: T
    // Found: T?
    return Require.notNull(maxOrNull, "Collection is empty.")
}
```

But if I replace `@NN` to `@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`, no error:

```
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
public static <T> T notNull(@Nullable T nullable, String message) throws NullPointerException {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(nullable, message);
}
```

Comment: What package/library is that `@Nonnull` from?

Comment: @al3c jsr305: `javax.annotation.Nonnull`

Comment: @al3c com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305 `javax.annotation.Nonnull`